# Varbinary to String in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I was trying to create a self encrypt way and decrypt way by converting it on varbinary, but the problem is that when I tried to decrpyt it, the result is way more different than the encrypted string.

```js
var name = "JUAN KARLOS"; //Random name
var a = name.ToArray();
byte[] b = new byte[a.Length];
byte[] c = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a);
c.CopyTo(b, 0);
string d = BitConverter.ToString(b);
d = d.Replace("-", "");
d = @"0x" + d;
```

This is the way I'm doing with encrypting the result is:

```js
0x4A55414E204B41524C4F53
```

and this is how I do my decryption:

```js
byte[] e = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(d);
string f = Convert.ToBase64String(e);
string g = String.Format(f);
```

and the result is:

```js
MHg0QTU1NDE0RTIwNEI0MTUyNEM0RjUz
```

Did it change the value because I replaced the "-" to ""?

Comment: This is not encryption, this is encoding. It's the same data in a different form. Also most likely the issue is that the process of encoding is different from the decoding process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to get the result:

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(2, hex.Length - 2)
            .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
            .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Main

```
        var name = "JUAN KARLOS"; //Random name
        var a = name.ToArray();
        byte[] b = new byte[a.Length];
        byte[] c = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a);
        c.CopyTo(b, 0);
        string d = BitConverter.ToString(b);
        d = d.Replace("-", "");
        d = @"0x" + d;
       //d="0x4A55414E204B41524C4F53"



        byte[] t = StringToByteArray(d);
        string tt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(t);
```

The result will be:

```
JUAN KARLOS
```